# how upgrade swagger2 to swagger3 in plain spring project

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

In our spring-webmvc project we are using the following code to configure swagger2, now we want to upgrade to swagger3, so we added springdoc-openapi-ui in pom file, what changes we need to make in our swagger-configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.hjk.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }
    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(title, description, version, termsOfServiceUrl, contact, license, licenseUrl);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `@EnableSwagger2`
and change your `Docket api()` like this.

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("SpringShop API"));}
```

For more details Please refer to this docs https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox.